# how to implement in-app purchase in my android application?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

How to implement in-app purchase in my android application??

I referred

http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_integrate.html#billing-service

this link but I don't understand Binding to the MarketBillingService step.

please give me proper example..

Comment: The example you ask for is at http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_integrate.html#billing-download

Comment: You can look into this library http://www.robotmedia.net/2011/06/android-billing-library-in-app-billing-made-simple/

Comment: Here is my solution library https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26601734/how-to-implement-in-app-purchase-of-application-android/68227056#68227056

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is another blog post explaining In App Purchase:

http://blog.blundellapps.com/simple-inapp-billing-payment/

I've also recently written an overview with a flowchart to try and explain InApp Purchase:

http://blog.blundellapps.com/overview-of-android-in-app-billing-flowchart/

[image]

Comment: Hi, great tutorial!
It works great for testing.

But where can I switch from testing to real purchase?