# How to limit the content on a free app?

Tags: android, google-play

I have a app I want to put up on googleplay and it´s going to cost.
But I also want the users to be able to download a free/trial version with limited content.

What is the best way to do that? and how can I know if the user has paid for it or not?

I am new to this so if this question is to "stupid" please write below what I did wrong and not just give me a minus.

Comment: I've seen many apps with a Trial version and a Paid version. It will be a bit longer to make, but it guarantees the fact that the user needs to buy the Paid version to get access to whatever content you're putting in that one.

Comment: Library Projects (for more look here) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711967/best-way-to-have-paid-and-free-version-of-an-android-app or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4740319/bulk-publishing-of-android-apps/4740728#4740728

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP, you need to decide if the purchase will come from "in app purchase" or the "Play Store"

**In App Purchase**
This route is to unlock features by purchasing a license within the app. Here is a good post by another user: [how to implement in-app purchase in my android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10792465/how-to-implement-in-app-purchase-in-my-android-application)

**Play Store**
As raybaybay has already mentioned, this is when you'd have two different applications (two seperate .apk files) one for paid and one for free. This is a little more work as you're writing the two applications in parallel.

Comment: Thx Greg Hilston and zgc7009! This is what I thought well I will just build a free version with less content...

Thx again!